Why is there no parameter \emergencytolerance?
If overfull boxes cannot be removed by rewording, layout changes etc., there are basically two strategies for removing them:

Increase the value of \tolerance
Increase the value of \emergencystretch

A frequently cited advantage of the second strategy is that increasing \emergencystretch only affects "bad" paragraphs (i. e. paragraphs that cannot be typeset satisfying \tolerance) and does not change "good" paragraphs (i. e. paragraphs that can be typeset satisfying \tolerance).
On the other hand, the way \emergencystretch changes the line-breaking process doesn't seem quite right to me: \emergencystretch is added to the stretchability of each line when computing badnesses. Thus, increasing \emergencystretch reduces the badnesses in the third pass, but leaves the other parameters that are included in the calculation of the total demerits (\hyphenpenalty, \adjdemerits, \doublehyphendemerits, ...) unchanged. This reduces the influence of badnesses, while the influence of lines ending with a hyphen etc. increases. Furthermore, the additional stretchability has a different effect for lines that have only four spaces than for lines that have ten spaces.
(I'm aware that \emergencystretch can be useful, e. g. for automatic typesetting, because by setting \emergencystretch sufficiently high depending on \hsize, you can ensure that overfull boxes never occur [unless the input contains something strange like an unhyphenatable word that is wider than the line]. \tolerance=10000 also never produces overfull boxes, but may lead to horrible line-breaking decisions.)
I wonder why there is no parameter \emergencytolerance (or whatever a suitable name would be) that allows you to optionally specify a value that TeX's line breaking algorithm uses as tolerance in the third pass. The third pass would then work something like this:

There is a parameter called \emergencytolerance with a default value of -1.
If the second pass fails and \emergencystretch is positive or \emergencytolerance is nonnegative, then the third pass is executed.
The procedure for the third pass is as follows: If \emergencystretch is positive, then this value is added to the stretchability of each line when computing badnesses. If \emergencytolerance is nonnegative, then this value is used as the limit for the badnesses instead of \tolerance, otherwise \tolerance is used as in the second pass.

This would allow you to typeset "bad" paragraphs without overfull boxes, without changing the "good" paragraphs and without the disadvantages of increasing \emergencystretch as described above. Why is this (presumably easy to implement) feature not available at least in newer engines such as eTeX or pdfTeX (Knuth's TeX is basically frozen)?

In Luatex you could in theory inplement this in Lua in a hypehention callback, in classic tex "why" question aways have the same answer, D E Knuth did what he could do to get TeX3 out then froze it for ever for new features just accepting bug reports.

In LuaMetaTeX you can have as many parpasses as you wish, with the penalties and tolerance you want, as well as font expansion to the amount you find OK. And you can enter the parpasses conditionally depending on various parameters.

@DavidCarlisle Yes, there are no new features for classic TeX, but I am also referring to newer engines such as pdfTeX. In eTeX, for example, there is a parameter \lastlinefit, which does not exist in classic TeX.

@user227621 in practice etex isn't a lot less frozen (athough we did get \expanded added to all engines)

To follow up on my comment (maybe not really an answer to your question, but I think people could benefit from being aware).
As David writes in the comment it is not so easy to answer why something was not added. I have heard that LuaTeX is frozen, so it will likely not be added there, but I hope you feel revealed by the information that it is nowadays possible, in LuaMetaTeX.
As indicated in the comment it is possible to do much more than just increasing the tolerance. The minimal example below, however, only adds two more parpasses, with increased tolerance.
\setuppapersize[A6]

\showmakeup[page]

\startsetups align:pass:test
    \pretolerance 100
    \tolerance    200
    \parpasses    2
        threshold            0.025pt
        tolerance            400
      next
        threshold            0.025pt
        tolerance            800
    \relax
\stopsetups

\starttext

\samplefile{hawking}

\page[yes]

\setupalignpass[test]
% \tracingonline2
% \tracingpasses2

\samplefile{hawking}

\stoptext

The two pages side-by-side:

Uncommenting the tracing macros will show some more information in the terminal.
By the way, this adds almost nothing to the runtime. On a 300 pages book I think 4 extra passes (including expansion) added less than a second. (So, this is not really where TeX spends its time...)
